# Auto differentiation library for Python

Tags: math, simulation

I'm looking for an [automatic differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation) library for Python.  My two most desired features are that it just works without muss or fuss, and that it's likely to be around for a while.

I know that's a big ask, because these seem to still be new and nitch.

I have found [auto-diff](https://pypi.org/project/auto-diff/) on Pypi, but I don't know if it's the best candidate.

Comment: What does best mean ?  Lowest size, fastest, cheapest, clearest code documentation, most users ...

Comment: Thanks. Edited.